# Loading controller from the URL Parameters or URL-Routing or _remap

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing, remap

I am new to CodeIgniter and wanna implement something like the below example. In the below example, Adidas is a brand name, Casual-Shoes is the type of shoes, Winterwear, Summerwear are some other types.

- http://www.myntra.com/winterwear
- http://www.myntra.com/adidas
- http://www.myntra.com/casual-shoes/
- http://www.myntra.com/sales

and I know that winterwear, Adidas, casual-shoes are not the controller names or method names. In my project, I wanna implement something like this where index file will find out whether Adidas is a brand name, or winterwear is type of season and if found, then load respective controller by passing the arguments.

I think, this is the part of URL Routing or checking db and then, get the controller or method name. Even, Breadcrumbs should work like this?

Any help with the code example would be appreciated.

Comment: study routes in codeigniter and htaccess

Comment: I tried to get from URI Routes but nothing is working. I am not understanding the approach.

Comment: Can someone please help me with the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Above thing can be done using _remap function/method. You can read more about it from here - http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-remove-index-php-minimize-url/